# Why is Django ignoring my ROOT_URLCONF setting?

Tags: django

I tried setting `ROOT_URLCONF` in settings.py in my project (called registration) to a variety of strings: `ROOT_URLCONF = 'registration.urls'`, `ROOT_URLCONF = 'foo.urls'`, `ROOT_URLCONF = 'monkey.urls'`, `ROOT_URLCONF = 'registration.registration.urls'`.

Regardless, I get this output on my home page:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://78.198.124.245/
Directory indexes are not allowed here.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file.
```

Why is that? Here is the file I am using to configure Passenger (passenger_wsgi.py). This file is located in "/home/david/registration/registration/."

```
import os, sys

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "registration.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
sys.path.append("/home/david/registration/registration")
sys.path.append("/home/david/registration/registration/app")
```

/home/david/registration/registration/urls.py looks like this.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url, http

def myFunction(request):
    return http.HttpResponse("A mapped URL")

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'myFunction')
)
```

Why is my Django application completely ignoring my ROOT_URLCONF setting and returning the same output every time I access my home page?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of your tries actually resides in python path. If the path is `/home/david/registration/registration` and the urls are in `/home/david/registration/registration/urls.py` then what should be the relative path from first to second?